# MySQL: LOAD DATA with time/dates with timezone information

Tags: mysql, date, datetime, date-formatting

I have text file that comes with timestamps of the form `Fri, 05 Jan 2013 05:50:00 +0800`. I don't know how I can read the file into my MySQL database. `Fri, 05 Jan 2013 05:50:00` would work just fine with `'%a, %d %M %Y %H:%i:%s'`, but the `+xx00` throws everything off. That doesn't seem to be [supported](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_str_to_date.asp).

Is there a way to import the text file as is, or do I need to preprocess it first to handle the timezone information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little complicated, but the answer is yes.

1. First of all, you must replace your timezone information from `+0800` to `+08:00`, because MySQL only support this kind of offset expression.
2. Use `STR_TO_DATE` to get a standard datetime: `STR_TO_DATE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(your_time_str, ' ', 5), '%a, %d %M %Y %H:%i:%s')`;
3. [Optional, if you need] Convert the standard time string from timezone described in `your_time_str` to server timezone: `CONVERT_TZ(standard_time_str, SUBSTRING_INDEX(your_time_str, ' ', -1), SELECT @@global.time_zone)`

So the final statement is something like this:

```
CONVERT_TZ(STR_TO_DATE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(your_time_str, ' ', 5), '%a, %d %M %Y %H:%i:%s'), SUBSTRING_INDEX(your_time_str, ' ', -1), SELECT @@global.time_zone)
```